# Replacing figure with figure* globally in Pandoc-created documents

Tags: floats, environments, pandoc

I use Pandoc to create TeX files as chapter templates that are then fed back into Pandoc to create the final PDF. This sets some limitations, since some of the ways Pandoc writes TeX is hard-coded.

One problem I encountered with this is with figures in `two-column` documents. I would like to have figures that span both columns. I know this could be achieved with using `figure*` instead of `figure`, but since Pandoc writes the figure code, I'm stuck with figure everywhere in the document. **Can I globally define that `figure`, is replaced by `figure*` instead?** I've tried various ways of trying to redefine the command, but haven't been able to get them to work.

I found that somebody had change the default settings for figure floats in Pandoc-created documents with the following code:

```
% Overwrite \begin{figure}[htbp] with \begin{figure}[H]
\usepackage{float}
\let\origfigure=\figure
\let\endorigfigure=\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
  \origfigure[H]
}{%
  \endorigfigure
}
```

I tried changing this to

```
\usepackage{float}
\let\origfigure=\figure
\let\endorigfigure=\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
  \origfigure*
}{%
  \endorigfigure*
}
```

But the `\renewenvironment` seems to change only the arguments, not the command itself. Is there better solution? Am I simply using the wrong syntax?

Comment: use `\begin{figure*}` not `\origfigure*` (which is not the same thing at all)

Comment: Where, exactly, should I use \begin{figure*} in my redefinition?

Comment: where you have `\origfigure*` (and same for the end)

Answer (score 4):

The correct solution is

```
\usepackage{float}
\let\origfigure=\figure
\let\endorigfigure=\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
  \begin{figure*}
}{%
  \end{figure*}
}
```

Comment: Does it really worked with you? It keeps asking me for /begin{document}.

Comment: It does. There is probably some other problem with you template. You typically see the /begin{document} error when some other environment is not ended properly.